# Printing field value on label

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have created a menu item, which i added onto an ActionPane. The Menu Item runs an Output menu item which runs a Report. What I want to accomplish is, when a user clicks the menu item I want AX2012 to directly print the report.

```
display str ItemID(ItemId  itemId)
{
    str                 returnValue;
    InventTable         inventTable;
    ;

        returnValue = this.ItemId;

    return returnValue;

}
```

I am returning the ItemId on the report. How I can trigger AX2012 to directly print the report (with the ItemId) when the menu button is clicked?

Comment: In which form action pane you have modified to add newly created menu item? From where you get the item id? What are you trying to achieve with above display method where you are not using the parameter as well as Invent table variable.

Comment: I have added the button in the Released Products form, i want to retrieve the Item ID from there. I am not sure what you mean with the last sentence?

Comment: To get the item id from the form, assign the data source as inventtable on the menuitem on action pane. Then you can get the data source buffer as args.record() in class main method.

Comment: In above display method, you are not using parameter(itemid) and also the variable (inventtable). So I am not sure what you expecting with that method.